# How to change domain of a field in IBExpert?

Tags: firebird, ibexpert

I wanted to change a field from D_ALPHA2NOTNULL to D_ALPHA8NOTNULL, so that I am able to use more chars. Unfortunately if I am trying to change the domain I am getting an error message:

```
action cancelled by trigger (2) to preserve data integrity.
Cannot update index segment used by an Integrity Constraint.
```

Comment: Drop the constraint, change the field, add the constraint.

Comment: Please provide the current DDL of the table, including any constraints.

Comment: It's a bit difficult, I guess. I have got too many dependencies on this field so that I cannot just drop the constraint. I will leave you a pastebin link, because it will be a lot clearer I think.
https://pastebin.com/YctutiQB

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no other way. And all those dependencies need to be changed as well.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Especially this field is used in so many other tables / views, so it is too error-prone. I think that's not a good idea. But why isn't it possible to change just the domain? It is nothing special than changing the char length from 2 to 8 - or does some interesting things happen in the background?

Comment: I don't know the underlying reasons, but this change is explicitly disallowed, which means that this was done on purpose.

Comment: FlameRobin used to work for that, simply click the `Generate Rebuild Script` for the column then copy the change script from IBExpert. I rarely use it now and had to make some changes to get 0.9.3 to work with FB3, mainly update the fbclient.dll.